# How to use Node.js nested Async forEachSeries loop

Tags: node.js

*Using coffeescript to code*
[One solution | see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690622/node-js-callbacks-async-foreach-nested-loop-with-waterfall-flow)

I have two loops. I want to take each value from array 'a' and then loop through all the values of 'b' process them and move to next value in array 'a'

output expected:

```
1 a b c
2 a b c
3 a b c
```

Error I see:

```
 [ 1, 2, 3 ]

 [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]

 1
 2
 3

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
   at Object.forEachSeries(~/src/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:103:17)




  Async = require('async')

  @a = [1,2,3]
  @b = ['a','b','c']

  console.dir @a
  console.dir @b

  Async.forEachSeries @a, (aa , cbLoop1) ->
    console.log aa
    cbLoop1()
    Async.forEachSeries @b, (bb , cbLoop2) ->
      #here will be some callback that I need to process before moving to next value in
      #b array
      console.log bb
      cbLoop2()
```

Comment: Can you update with actual javascript code for nodejs?  Its really hard to get a handle on where the problem lies with this pseudo code.

Comment: @jeremy I have re posted the code thanks !

Comment: Thanks, the coffee script bit was throwing me off a bit too.  Looks like Brandon beat me to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `Async.forEachSeries` call takes a callback, which changes the value of `this`

```coffee-script
Async.forEachSeries @a, (aa , cbLoop1) ->
  # inside the callback, the value of `this` has changed,
  # so @b is undefined!
```

Use the `=>` syntax to keep the value of `this` inside the callback:

```coffee-script
Async.forEachSeries @a, (aa , cbLoop1) =>
  console.log aa
  cbLoop1()
  Async.forEachSeries @b, (bb , cbLoop2) ->
    # use `=>` again for this callback if you need to access this (@) inside
    # this callback as well
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick feedback .. i really appreciate . I was trying to play more with the loop and again I am stuck in a design issue.
Say if i replace this **console.log bb** with a method that has a callback EG: `start param1 (err , returnValue) -> console.log returnValue` my loops goes hay wire ..ny inputs will be helpful Thanks